# ArcMap Elevation Graph Min/Max Values

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, graph

I'm trying to create elevation graphs from a set of line features and raster elevation file, while the Stack Profile tool from ArcMap can do that, I need to modify the min/max values of the y-axis to make them uniform. I know I can manually change the values but I need to be able to automate the process of changing those values.

I have looked all over to find if there's way to do that, and the closest answer I got was the `addSeriesBarMinMax` function, which does not work for my graph. This is a test run of the code:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace="D:"

graph="test1.grf"
output_graph="test.grf"

graph=arcpy.Graph()

graph.addSeriesBarMinMax(graph, 400, 510)
arcpy.SaveGraph_management(graph,output_graph)
```

And I get this error:

```
  arcpy.SaveGraph_management(graph,output_graph)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 5473, in SaveGraph
    raise e
RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool
```

Is there any way for me to modify the min/max y-values from ArcPy?

Comment: Try setting workspace to r"D:\"

Comment: No.... it gives me the exact same error. Thanks though

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are losing your reference to `test1.grf`.  Try naming one of your parameters differently, such as using `input_graph` as your input variable name.

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r"D:"

input_graph = "test1.grf"
output_graph = "test.grf"

graph = arcpy.Graph()

graph.addSeriesBarMinMax(input_graph, 400, 510)
arcpy.SaveGraph_management(graph,output_graph)
```